# Angular2 - Debug primeng library

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular4 and installed primeng by:

```
npm install primeng
```

Now I can use primeng but cannot debug it because `node_modules\primeng` contains only the `js` (after `ts` compilation) files.

What can I do in order to debug primeng typescript in my project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've cloned primeng lib from github url into another project and managed to debug it.

Comment: I understand you cloned the PrimeNG lib itself, but how you debugged or what you did to enable debugging in your project that uses it seems to be missing from this answer.

Comment: @jimmygoggle Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem with primeng. They don't provide `ts` files with the bundle, so only way to access those `ts` files is via their Github project.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/components/

I ended up debugging/editing/enhancing their `js` files. Also, we excluded the `primeng` module from our `.gitignore` so that our changes are not wiped out everytime we do a fresh `npm install`

Comment: They provide `js.map` files that contain typescript code